# Resizing the panels on gridlayout

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, grid-layout

I'm trying to make a simple ui game with Java swing. Here is my target layout design: (all panels have same width, excuse my drawing)

[image: layout design]

I need 3 small height panel and 1 large panel

I used `GridLayout` with 4x1. I added some buttons to first panel.

```
mainFrame = new JFrame("Basket Game");
mainFrame.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 1));


options = new JPanel();
options.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
options.setBorder( new TitledBorder("Options Menu") );

options.add(settings);
options.add(start);
options.add(pause);
options.add(reset);
options.add(exit);

mainFrame.add(options);
```

But it makes the first panel too big.

[image: form]

How can I set a size for these panels or should I use different layout pattern.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With a `GridLayout`, all cells in the grid have the same size, that's why your panel has 1/4 of the total height.

You may consider using a vertical [`BoxLayout`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/BoxLayout.html):

```
JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
mainPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(mainPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
// add the panels to mainPanel, then
mainFrame.setContentPane(mainPanel);
```

Here is an example, with three panels containing one button each, and one panel having a bigger size :

```
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();

        JPanel p1 = new JPanel();
        p1.add(new JButton("11111"));
        JPanel p2 = new JPanel();
        p2.add(new JButton("222222"));
        JPanel p3 = new JPanel();
        p3.add(new JButton("3333"));
        JPanel p4 = new JPanel();
        p4.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 400));

        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
        mainPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(mainPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        mainPanel.add(p1);
        mainPanel.add(p2);
        mainPanel.add(p3);
        mainPanel.add(p4);

        frame.setContentPane(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: I think you were saying X axis. However, the size is still same. Here is picture with Y axis: http://i.imgur.com/D6OsGuQ.png X axis: http://i.imgur.com/uNV729m.png